# Store color for data ranges and use in case statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, comparison-operators

I have a data set as below. [Fiddle URL](https://rextester.com/AZVIXS99554)

[image]

I need to get the color of given number using operators in above table.

For example;

When I called the function `getColor(6)`, should return `PURPLE`.

When I called the function `getColor(0)`, should return `RED`.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Why shouldn't getColor(6) return blue AND purple?

Comment: @SalmanA In this case `BLUE` should return for numbers between `0.01` and `4.99` only

Comment: @Bishan Request you to see my updated answer I have tested and it is working for 0, 6 and values between the ranges 0.01 and 4.99.

Comment: Do you really need to use this table structure? Can't you define higher and lower limit? So you would only need a query with a between. For example purple: lower limit 5 higher limit 8 (or 7.999).

Comment: @EzLo Need to define something like `YELLOW` for `passValue > 15`. `BLACK` for `passValue < -10.` So yeah, need to use this structure

Comment: It's a very confusing way of storing these rules. If you have 100 colors you won't be able to interpret easily by seeing the data which value returns a particular color, since there will be more than 1 rule that applies.

Comment: @EzLo Yeah, you are correct. Any idea for a better solution than this to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create matching condition for each operator using `CASE` expressions:

```
DECLARE @val NUMERIC(10) = 6;

SELECT /* TOP 1 */ *
FROM #range_color
CROSS APPLY (SELECT @val - range_number) AS ca(diff)
WHERE CASE WHEN diff <  0 AND range_operator = '<'  THEN 1 END = 1
OR    CASE WHEN diff <= 0 AND range_operator = '<=' THEN 1 END = 1
OR    CASE WHEN diff >= 0 AND range_operator = '>=' THEN 1 END = 1
OR    CASE WHEN diff >  0 AND range_operator = '>'  THEN 1 END = 1
ORDER BY ABS(diff)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll check this and update you.

Comment: What do you think about @Mano's answer? It's also giving the expected answer and there is no need of creating matching conditions for each operator.

Comment: That answer does not check range_operator and your data mostly contains `>=`. Try adding `6, '<', 4, 'CYAN'` in your data and check.

Comment: Yeah. return `BLUE` instead of `CYAN`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following query.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getColor
(@Colorcode decimal(18,2))
RETURNS  VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @color VARCHAR(10)='RED'
SELECT TOP (1) @color=range_color FROM range_color 
WHERE range_number between range_number AND @Colorcode - (CASE WHEN 
@Colorcode=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Order by range_number desc
RETURN @color
END
```

I have tried another one query,

```
DECLARE @val DECIMAL(18,2)=1

DECLARE @temp TABLE(color VARCHAR(10),flag BIT,range_number NUMERIC(10),diff int)
DECLARE @temp1 TABLE(color VARCHAR(10),range_number NUMERIC(10),Operator VARCHAR(10),range_color_id INT)
INSERT INTO @temp1
SELECT range_color,range_number,range_operator,range_color_id FROM range_color

WHILE(0<(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @temp1))
BEGIN

DECLARE @operator VARCHAR(10),@range_color_id INT

SELECT TOP 1 @operator=Operator,@range_color_id=range_color_id FROM @temp1
INSERT INTO @temp
EXEC ('select range_color,CASE WHEN '+ @val +' '+@operator+' range_number  
THEN 1 else 0 END,range_number,'+@val+'- range_number from range_color WHERE  
range_color_id='+@range_color_id)
DELETE TOP (1) FROM @temp1
END

SELECT * FROM @temp  WHERE flag=1  ORDER BY ABS(diff)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mano. I'll check this and update you.

Answer (score 1):

Request you to have a look into this below query.

```
declare @PassingValues int = 0
declare @MatchingRange int

select top 1 @MatchingRange = range_number from #RangeColor where range_number = @PassingValues
order by range_color_id     
if(@@ROWCOUNT <= 0)
begin
if(@MatchingRange is not null)
begin
    select top 1 * from #RangeColor where range_number <= @MatchingRange 
    order by range_color_id
end
else
begin
    Select top 1 @MatchingRange = range_number from #RangeColor where range_number < @PassingValues 
    order by range_number desc      
    if(@MatchingRange IS NULL)
    begin
        select top 1 @MatchingRange = range_number from #RangeColor where range_number > @PassingValues 
        order by range_number                   
        select top 1 * from #RangeColor where range_number > @MatchingRange 
        order by range_color_id
    end
    else
    begin
        select top 1 * from #RangeColor where range_number <= @MatchingRange 
        order by range_color_id desc        
    end
end
end
else
begin
    select top 1 * from #RangeColor where range_number = @PassingValues
    order by range_color_id     
end
```

Comment: @Bishan Please check my latest updated answer and I hope it will work sure. I have added @@ROWCOUNT to check exact match.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to change your table to something easier to interpret and query. The following statements creates the new table and transforms your rules to the new format. Later on you can see how easy it is to query this new table.

The table I suggest has Lower + Higher limit for each color:

```
CREATE TABLE UpdatedRangeColor (
    range_color_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    range_color VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LowerLimit INT,
    HigherLimit INT)
```

This converts current rules to new table:

```
CREATE TABLE UpdatedRangeColor (
    range_color_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    range_color VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LowerLimit INT,
    HigherLimit INT)


;WITH HigherRule AS
(
    SELECT
        R.*,
        IsRuleHigher = CASE WHEN R.range_operator LIKE '%>%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM
        range_color AS R
),
TemporaryLimits AS
(
    select 
        R.*,
        TemporaryLowerLimit = CASE WHEN R.IsRuleHigher = 1 THEN R.range_number END,
        TemporaryHigherLimit = CASE WHEN R.IsRuleHigher = 0 THEN R.range_number END,
        Partition = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY
                CASE WHEN R.IsRuleHigher = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
            ORDER BY
                ABS(R.range_number))
    from 
        HigherRule AS R
)
INSERT INTO UpdatedRangeColor (
    range_color_id,
    range_color,
    LowerLimit,
    HigherLimit)
SELECT
    T.range_color_id,
    T.range_color,
    LowerLimit = CASE 
        WHEN T.IsRuleHigher = 1 THEN T.TemporaryLowerLimit
        ELSE LAG(T.TemporaryHigherLimit, 1, -999) OVER (PARTITION BY T.IsRuleHigher ORDER BY T.Partition DESC) END,
    HigherLimit = CASE
        WHEN T.IsRuleHigher = 1 THEN LEAD(T.TemporaryLowerLimit, 1, 999) OVER (PARTITION BY T.IsRuleHigher ORDER BY T.Partition ASC)
        ELSE T.TemporaryHigherLimit END
FROM
    TemporaryLimits AS T
```

Rows inserted are the following:

```
range_color_id  range_color LowerLimit  HigherLimit
1               RED         -999        0
2               BLUE        0           5
3               PURPLE      5           8
4               ORANGE      8           12
5               GREEN       12          999
```

Then you can simply issue a direct query with 2 conditions (make sure to review where the equal sign should be included):

```
DECLARE @ParameterValue FLOAT = 5.648

SELECT
    *
FROM
    UpdatedRangeColor AS U
WHERE
    @ParameterValue >= U.LowerLimit AND
    @ParameterValue < U.HigherLimit
```

Result:

```
range_color_id  range_color LowerLimit  HigherLimit
3               PURPLE      5           8
```

The con about this approach is maintaining this new table, you will have to keep consistency in the records when inserting new values or updating (or use this procedure to translate the original rows to the new format each time new records are added).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll check this and update you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your intention to print those values lies in range, you can use the following stored procedure:

```
Create Proc MyProc(@Range Int)
As
Begin
Select @Range As RangeValue, Case When @Range = 0 Then
        'Red'
        When @Range > 0 And @Range<5 Then
        'Blue'
        When @Range >= 5 And @Range <8 Then
        'Purple'
        When @Range >= 8 And @Range <12 Then
        'Orange'
        When @Range >=12 Then
        'Green'
        End As ColorName
End
Go
 -- execute procedure..
Exec MyProc 3
```